# Не определяет контролер AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-routing

Есть модуль AngularJS и контролер

**Модуль**

```
var AngApp = angular.module('AngApp', ['ngRoute']);
AngApp.controller('LoginController', LoginController);
var configFunction = function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: "/Account/Login",
    controller: LoginController
    });
}
configFunction.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider'];
AngApp.config(configFunction);
```

**Контроллер:**

```
function LoginController($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.loginForm = {
        emailAdress: '',
        password: '',
        rememberMe: false,
        returnUrl: $routeParams.returnUrl
    };
//todo
}
LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];
```

**Представление:**

```
<html ng-app="AngApp">
....
<li><a href="/#/login">Log In</a></li>
....
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при запуске появляется ошибка:

```
'LoginController' is undefined
```

И естественно, маршрутизация также не работает.